# MUI SwipeableDrawer not a JSX.Element issue

Tags: typescript, material-ui, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I am using SwipeableDrawer component on my project. However, there is an error during the build process that pointing to the typings.

I have upgraded the @types/react and @types/react-dom to v18, but the error still persist.

[image: MUI SwipeableDrawer not a JSX.Element]

Answer (score 0):

Remove node_modules and yarn.lock or package-lock.json and install pnpm and install your dependencies.

[pnpm installation](https://pnpm.io/installation)